# Not able to send email using custom template in magento 1.9.2 community edition

Tags: magento-1.9, email, email-templates

Hello guys i am trying to send an email in magento using custom email templates. But I am getting exception I have installed SMTP Pro Extension.

I am listing code here:-

My config.xml

```
<template>
  <email>
    <custom_abc_email_template  module="custom_abc">
      <label>Custom Template</label>
      <file>custom_abc_templates/customTemplate.html</file>  // this specifies the path where the custom template is located
      <type>html</type>
    </custom_abc_email_template>
  </email>
</template>
```

code of my controller action

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault('custom_abc_email_template');
$emailTemplate->setSenderName('custom template');
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('abc@demomail.com');
$emailTemplate->send('abc@demomail.com','Forgot Password');
```

My Template file code

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="action-content">
            <h1>Custom Abc,</h1>
            <p><strong>Your new password is:</strong> trolled</p>
            <p>You can change your password at any time by logging into <a href="{{store url="customer/account/"}}">your account</a>.</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In exception.log

```
2016-04-11T10:03:18+00:00 ERR (3): exception 'Exception' with message
'This letter cannot be sent.' in /var/www/html/MMM/app/code/local/Aschroder/SMTPPro/Model/Email/Template.php:40
```

In aschroder_smtppro.log

```
2016-04-11T10:03:18+00:00 DEBUG (7): Email is not valid for sending, 
this is a core error that often means there's a problem with your email templates.
```

setting of email in backend
[image]

Comment: `$emailTemplate->send('abc@demomail.com','Forgot Password',,$storeId=null);` not sure where is problem but try that clear your cache too

Comment: i got one more error now in my system.xml  2016-04-11T10:51:24+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 3 passed to Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Template::send() must be of the type array, null given, called in /var/www/html/MMM/app/code/local/$

Comment: `$cus=array();
$emailTemplate->send('abc@demomail.com','Forgot Password',$cus ,$storeId=null);` try that

Comment: sir it removed the latest error is still same mail is not going

Comment: did you the custom email it is going simple email?

Comment: magento mails are going sir like if i ll do forgot password and put customer email i ll receive the mail to reset password. Well I am on my localhost

Comment: Do you added `<html></html>`  in your template??

Comment: earlier i did not add but now I have added but still getting same error

Answer (score 2):

use below code you were not processing the template..

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
                        ->loadDefault('custom_abc_email_template');                                 

$emailTemplate->setSenderName('custom template');
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('abc@demomail.com');
$emailTemplateVariables = array();
$processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);
$emailTemplate->send('abc@demomail.com','Forgot Password', $emailTemplateVariables,$storeId=null);
```

try to send direct email it is working or not

```
$html="
put your html content here
blah blah

";
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName('Your Name');
$mail->setToEmail('Youe Email');
$mail->setBody('Mail Text / Mail Content');
$mail->setSubject('Mail Subject');
$mail->setFromEmail('Sender Mail Id');
$mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
$mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

try {
$mail->send();
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Your request has been sent');
$this->_redirect('');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
$this->_redirect('');
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help but it is not working can you tell me is my template is correct because in aschroder_smtppro.log  m getting Email is not valid for sending, 
this is a core error that often means there's a problem with your email templates.

Comment: did you load the email in admin panel and check that?

Comment: it is loading and showing the preview

Comment: remove this and try with simple text `{{store url="customer/account/"}}`

Comment: still not working

Comment: updated the code with simple email check it is working or not?

Comment: sir when i removed the code which is checking the validation i got the mail but it was blank

Comment: `echo $processedTemplate;` and check your template is processed or not

Comment: kindly add the template file path too

Comment: see my path app/locale/en_US/template/email/custom_abc_templates/customTemplate.html

Comment: $processedTemplate is giving me empty in log

Comment: did you defined the template inside  `<global></global>` tag?

Comment: yes sir it is defined in global tag

Comment: sir i am getting the process template now but getting same error\