# Not getting emails from Magento custom form

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I made a custom form using instructions found at [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/comment-page-2/). I've created the form and it's appearing properly but the mails are not sending at all. I get an error 'Unable to Send email' which comes from the `catch` part of the code. Nothing in the system.log or exceptions.log files to give me a clue.

The form has an action of `domain.com/postajob/index/sendemail/` and my IndexController.php file looks like this

```
<?php
class BWD_JobForm_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
public function sendemailAction()
{
    //Fetch submited params
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $from_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    $from_name = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

    $mail = new Zend_Mail();
    $mail->setBodyText($params['role']);
    $mail->setFrom($from_email, $from_name);
    $mail->addTo($params['email'], $params['name']);
    $mail->setSubject('Test Post a Job Module for Magento');
    try {
        $mail->send();
    }
    catch(Exception $ex) {
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($ex->getMessage());
    }

    //Redirect back to index action of (this) inchoo-simplecontact controller
    $this->_redirect('thanks/');
}
}
?>
```

I've also tried methods mentioned [here](https://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/04/sending-emails-programmatically-in-magento/) and [here](http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-send-transactional-email/) but none of them work. For the record, mail sending is enabled in the configuration.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara This is custom email.

Comment: check this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/110326/not-able-to-send-email-using-custom-template-in-magento-1-9-2-community-edition

Comment: I've set the cron times to 1 minute and I've been trying it for hours now

Comment: Is it possible to get a more detailed description from exception rather than just 'Unable to send'?

Answer (score 0):

you can try below code for email this is always working for me.

```
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email')
->setToName($senderName)
->setToEmail($customerEmail)
->setBody($YourMSG)
->setSubject('Subject :')
->setFromEmail($senderEmail)
->setFromName($senderName)
->setType('html');

$mail->send(
```

And also you can try below code

```
$emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$emailTemplate->setSenderName('Name');
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('Email@provider.com');
$emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Subject');
$emailTemplate->send('Email@provider.com','ReciverName',$data);
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer for newbies? What's `$Data` for instance?

Comment: your data that you want to send with mail

Comment: Then what's 'msg'?

Comment: check updated answer